# Filter rows by last maximal value ordering by a time value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with an id, an ordering time value and a value. And for each group of ids, I would like to remove rows having a smaller value than rows having smaller time value.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 3L), "b"), 
                   time = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3),
                   value = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4))

> data
  id time value
1  a    0     1
2  a    1     1
3  a    2     2
4  b    0     3
5  b    1     1
6  b    2     2
7  b    3     4
```

So the result would be :

```
> data
  id time value
1  a    0     1
2  a    2     2
3  b    0     3
4  b    3     4
```

(For `id == b` rows where `time %in% c(3, 4)` are removed because the value `value` is smaller than when `time` is lower)

I was thinking about `lag`

```
data %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(time == 0 | lag(value, order_by = time) < value)

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: id [2]

      id  time value
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1      a     0     1
2      a     2     2
3      b     0     3
4      b     2     2
5      b     3     4
```

But it doesn't work as expected since it's a vectorized function, so instead the idea would be to use a "recursive lag function" or to check the last maximal value. I can do it recursively with a loop but I'm sure there is a more straightforward and high level way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you !

Comment: Sorry, I will try to rephrase it to make it more understandable.

Comment: Nvm, I understood it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, myVal := cummax(c(0, shift(value)[-1])), by=id][value > myVal][, myVal := NULL][]
   id time value
1:  a    0     1
2:  a    2     2
3:  b    0     3
4:  b    3     4
```

The first part of the chain uses `shift` and `cummax` to create the cumulative maximum of the lagged value variable. In `c(0, shift(value)[-1])`, 0 is added to supply a value lover than any in the variable. More generally, you could use `min(value)-1` the `[-1]` subsetting removes the first element of `shift`, which is NA. The second part of the chain selects observations where value is greater than the cumulative maximum. The final two chains remove the cumulative maximum variable and print out the result.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to perform a self anti/non-equi join using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) # v1.10.0
setDT(data)[!data, on = .(id, time > time, value <= value)]
#    id time value
# 1:  a    0     1
# 2:  a    2     2
# 3:  b    0     3
# 4:  b    3     4
```

Which is basically saying: "*If `time` is larger but `value` is less-equal, then I don't want these rows (`!` sign)*"

Comment: Wicked clever! I didn't know about non-equi joins -- thanks.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, thanks. It was added in the latest version and I keep finding it different uses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'id', we `filter` the rows where the 'value' is greater than the cumulative maximum of the 'lag' of the 'value' column

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(value > cummax(lag(value, default = 0)) ) 
#      id  time value
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1      a     0     1
#2      a     2     2
#3      b     0     3
#4      b     3     4
```

---

Or another option is `slice` after `arrange`ing by 'id' and 'time' (as the OP mentioned about the `order`

```
data %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     arrange(id, time) %>%
     slice(which(value > cummax(lag(value, default = 0))))
```

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) Thanks for this solution, does it only works when  the dataframe is previously ordered by `id` and `time` ?